# can this be canceled

Tags: malware

Limi1.com put up a malware alert on my computer, with an accompaining number to call. it stated for 29.97 it would be fixed. this was last night today I called my credit card, and was told a charge of $549.99 had been charged to my credit card from them. My question is ,I think you have 3 days to cancel any such charges. I did notify my credit card of this and asked them to check my paypal account. It was charged 3 times for 29.97.So tomorrow I will be calling both again credit and paypal, and will try the number for this company as well. I will tell them I want to cancel this year of service, which in the beginning was 29.97. I will see what takes place.

Comment: I suggest to make clear (using the '?' mark) if a sentence is a question.

Comment: You may have just been catfished...just maybe

Answer (score 3):

I hate to say it, but it sounds like you got tricked. It's a common scam for a pop-up to claim you have malware or viruses and "offer" you a to fix it for some fee. In reality you are usually paying for the privilege of giving hackers full control over your computer (if you installed software for them, that is).

Second, `limi1.com` doesn't appear to have anything on it, at least nothing that makes it past my script blockers (and I'm not willing to turn them off to check). That's not a good sign. A `whois` on `limi1.com` shows:

> Registrant Name: Oliver Hoger
>
> Registrant Organization: Virtual Real Estate Limited
>
> Registrant Street: Suite 4, 4 Giros Passage
>
> Registrant City: Gibraltar
>
> Registrant State/Province: Gibraltar
>
> Registrant Postal Code: GX11 1AA
>
> Registrant Country: Gibraltar
>
> Registrant Phone: +1.8553653669
>
> Registrant Email: seek99com@yahoo.com

The `admin` and `tech` entries are identical to this `registrant` entry. This seems awefuly suspicious for a company selling software services.

**Cancel all your cards, payment accounts, change all your passwords, and get a proper anti-virus**

Those charges are terrifying. You should assume that the "company" you were dealing with was a bunch of criminals. You should think carefully about what information you gave them directly, and what information was on your computer that they might have copied. As a general rule, you should cancel all your cards and change **ALL** your passwords (unless you are 100% sure that for a given card / account that information has never been anywhere near your computer).

You *may* be able to get some of that money back from your credit card company by saying that you only authorized $29.97 and the rest was fraud.

As for your computer, you should assume that these criminals have full control of it, best option is to put your important documents onto a USB stick, wipe the drive, and reinstall Windows (or take it to a tech shop to do the same). The second-best option would be to install a legitimate anti-virus (Symantec, McAfee, AVG, or the likes) and see what it finds in the way of malware.

Answer (score 1):

But the US has great consumer credit card protection. Call your CC company and tell them that you didn't authorize the charges. You cannot be held liable for more than $50 of invalid charges though most companies will not even charge you that. You may have to eat one $29.97 charge. You definitely need to cancel your card.

If anything from `limi1.com` was installed you will need to clean your computer very well. A full wipe and reinstall will not be unreasonable.

Comment: Assuming that they are in the US...